# switch statement is not executing

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have a C++ program that I must implement a switch statement in the program.  For a reason I do not know the switch statement is not executing.  The entire program looks like the following, http://pastebin.com/VxXFhGkQ.

The part of the program that I am having trouble with looks like the following,

```
void processCharges() // function to calculate charges
{
    int charges = 0;

    // switch statement cannot be applied to strings :(
    if(vehicle == "C")
    {
        cout << "TYPE OF VEHICLE: CAR" << endl;
        cout << "TIME IN: " << hh << ":" << mm << endl;
        cout << "TIME OUT: " << hhout << ":" << mmout << endl;
        cout << "======================================" << endl;

        thh = hhout - hh;

        tmm = mmout - mm;

        int tthh = 0;

        if(tmm > 0)
        {
            tthh = thh + 1;
        }
        else tthh = thh;

        cout << "TOTAL TIME PARKED: " << tthh << endl;

        switch(tthh) {
        case 1:
            if(tthh <= 3) {
                charges = 0;
                cout << "TOTAL CHARGES:$"<<charges << endl;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            if(tthh >= 4) {
                charges = tthh * 1.25;
                cout << "TOTAL CHARGES:$"<<charges << endl;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `vehicle` is of type `std::string`, right?

Comment: yes vehicle is a string.

Comment: this `switch(tthh) {
        case 1:
            if(tthh <= 3) {` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @njzk2 but `switch(tthh) { case 2: if(tthh >= 4) {` makes even less sense!

Comment: I believe the OP is treating the value as a label for the cases, i.e. "first case", "second case", etc.

Comment: I highly recommend you use more readable and meaningful variable names.  What does `tthh` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch(tthh) 
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        charges = 0;
        cout << "TOTAL CHARGES:$"<<charges << endl;
        break;
    default:
        charges = tthh * 1.25;
        cout << "TOTAL CHARGES:$"<<charges << endl;
        break;

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that tthh is of type int.  Consider using an unsigned int or checking for a negative number before using switch.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your variable `tthh` has a different value than 1 or 2. To find out what is the value add a `default` clause to your `switch` statement with a print statement and print out its value.

Comment: are you saying I have to make a case for each value of tthh?

Comment: That's what `switch` is for. If you want to check for ranges then use `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your case statement is written improperly. You can just take out the switch and make it an if else or an if else if. Right now it is looking for tthh to == 1 || 2

Comment: can a case specify a range of values?

Comment: No I double checked myself, and case statements can not use inequalities in C++. It would be easiest to move it to the if statement you have set up in there.

Answer (score 0):

You switch on `tthh`, test the case where it is 1, then test if it is less than or equal to 3 (which it would obviously be).

Then you test case 2, and test if it is more than or equal to 4, which it can't b (since `2 < 4`).

So basically, the only case where your switch does anything at all is if tthh == 1.

I would remove the switch altogether, as i doesn't seem to add anything.

Answer (score 0):

That switch statement doesnt make a lot of sense.  See comments below.

```
switch(tthh) {
    case 1:
        if(tthh <= 3) { //THIS WILL ALWAYS BE TRUE BECAUSE tthh is 1 here
            charges = 0;
            cout << "TOTAL CHARGES:$"<<charges << endl;
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        if(tthh >= 4) { // THIS WILL NEVER BE TRUE BECAUSE tthh is 2 here
            charges = tthh * 1.25;
            cout << "TOTAL CHARGES:$"<<charges << endl;
            break;
        }
}
```